# Css / HTML5 - Need help getting a youtube popup to appear using fancybox2

Tags: css, html, fancybox-2

I've been working on getting a youtube video to play as a pop-over in HTML5 using "fancybox".  Only I cannot get it to pop-up!  instead it always seems to open the page itself, which is completely against the point. I could use some advice on how to fix this, can you help?  I have looked on stack-overflow but did not find a clear answer to this use case.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--fancy box-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- /fancy box-->
        <!--fancy box-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

            /* This is basic - uses default settings */
            $("a#single_image").fancybox();
            /* Using custom settings */
            $("a#inline").fancybox({
                'hideOnContentClick': true
            });
            /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */
            $("a.group").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
                'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
                'speedIn'       :   600, 
                'speedOut'      :   200, 
                'overlayShow'   :   false
            });

        });
        </script>
        <!-- /fancy box-->

    </head>
    <body>



                            <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo&autoplay=1">Youtube</a><br>
                            <a class="iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo&autoplay=1">This goes to iframe</a><br >
                            <a class="iframe" href="http://www.example.com">This goes to iframe</a><br>
                            <a class="various iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">Youtube (iframe)</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting elements from javascript which are non existent, check the IDs an Class of the anchor tags... for example ""**a#single_image**" should refer to an anchor tag with the attribute **id='single_image'**, being not present, fancybox fails to initialize.
Same goes for **a#inline** and **a.group** ( it expects class='group' in the anchor )

Comment: Ok, so can I can get rid of those.  Only how do I fix my issue with the pop=up window not popping up?

Comment: I cannot answer this question without more info, paste the code you are trying to run.    
Also make sure that the path to the fancybox library is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same class as fancybox uses for iframe: "fancybox.iframe"

Also use an youtube link that is embed., then everythings works fine.

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/usiOu1ZKJ4o">Youtube (iframe)</a>
```

.

```
            $(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
```

Use the latest jquery library, the latest is now 1.9 you are using 1.4.

And also use fancybox.js instead of fancybox.pack.js. That should do the trick!! and also use fancybox.iframe as a class combining another class to trigger the fancybox function

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't solve my issue...  I added the css style to the head of my page, then added the link that you provided. it still directed me to a new page

Answer (score 0):

Oke, try this:
Make sure the links to script and css are correct. In my case the subfolders are js and css.

first link includes a youtube video
second link an image.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!--fancy box-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <!-- /fancy box-->
    <!--fancy box-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });

    });
    </script>
    <!-- /fancy box-->

</head>
<body>

    <ul class="list">

        <li>
            <a class=" various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">youtube</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="various" href="http://androidactivist.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/draw-something-koopa.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="http://androidactivist.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/draw-something-koopa.jpg" alt="" /></a>
         </li>
    </ul>
```